# servicios web Soap android

Tags: android, android-studio, webservice, soap

Consulta, como consumir un servico soap usando la libreria KSOAP2 android, el servicio web es: http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/aws_datosfoto.aspx?wsdl

para hacer uso de la libreria: NAMESPACE, URL, METHOD_NAME Y SOAP_ACTION. no se exactamente cuales son esos parametros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("Usuario", "x...x"); 
request.addProperty("Password", "x...x");
request.addProperty("Servicio", "x...x");
request.addProperty("Tipodocumento", "D");
request.addProperty("Nrodocumento", "x...x");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 
    System.out.println("Respuesta: " + envelope.getResponse().toString());
...
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace mucho que no uso Android, pero creo que esto podria ayudarte, segun el wsdl que compartes. Esas son las constantes y un poquito de como alguna vez use ksoap2 para consumir servicios SOAP en Android.

```
 final String NAMESPACE = "AFPrivado";
        final String URL="http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/aws_datosfoto.aspx";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Execute";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "AFPrivadoaction/AWS_DATOSFOTO.Execute";
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = false;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL,10000);

    try


 {
        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        response =(String) envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = false;
        response="";
    }

    return result;
}
```